Is there a way to load a 140mb+ Excel file in memory in streams in NodeJS?
I have Excel files, each can reach up to 150mb in size. I need to progressively load chunks of this file (batches of 1000 rows for example) so I can turn them into JSON and manipulate them.
I tried with XLSX library which didn't offer much support in stream reading. I've also tried ExcelJS but what I found always contains something like:
const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
await workbook.xlsx.readFile(inputFilePath);

So it always goes back to using XLSX's readFile() and I get a size error.
I also tried using Gnumeric to convert the Excel file to CSV to try and read it that way, but it also raised a size error.
I also tried using ExcelReader from the node-excel-stream package but it's not flexible since I need to define the schema of every sheet in the Excel file and I don't always have that information and I have Excel files that sometimes have an empty string '' in the headers row and I would like to give each empty header a distinct value (e.g. ___EMPTY_CELL_01_, etc.) to output my JSON object in a correct format.
Is there a way to do this?

xlsx files are ZIP packages containing XML files. You can't read them in batches just like that, the library has to decompress the files first, just like any ZIP package. There are other libraries with less overhead that are meant to only Excel files so they don't have to represent the entire workbook in memory

As for ExcelJS, have you seen this question?

Export them to .csv and use csv-parser such as:
const csv = require("csv-parser");
const fs = require("fs");

async function readCsv() {
  const results = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream("data.csv")
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("data", (data) => results.push(data))
      .on("end", () => {
        resolve(results);
      })
      .on("error", (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
}

async function main() {
  const result = await readCsv();
  console.log(result);
}

main();

140mb should be easy.
If your file is bigger than your PC RAM you need another solution.
